# Carbon format only years and days with leap year

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I'm trying to get diff between 2 dates but only with **years and days** but adding months to days, example:

```
$date1 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(02.02.2021); 
$date2 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(01.01.2000);
$date2->diff($date1)->format('Y d');
```

But if I use format without month, it will be omitted and won't be added to days.

```
21 years, 1 day
```

But real is

```
21 years, 1 month, 1 day
```

So I want for example

```
21 years, 32 days
```

So I did:

```
$days = $date2->diffInDays($date1)
$years = intval($days/ 365);
$days_minusYears = $days % 365;

$diff = "$years"."y"." $days_minusYears"."d",
```

Unfortunately It will skip leap years.
How to do It properly?

Comment: You would start by being _specific_ about what you actually mean by _“adding months to days”_. From your given example, it sounds like you just added 30 days - but not every month _has_ 30 days, so if you go just number of month times 30, you are not likely to get any sensible result IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe don't multiplicate months and days. Calculate days excluding years. I just want amount of days after excluding years.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. $dep doesn't exist in your first example.

Comment: @jspit post fixed

Comment: @Davidos January always has 31 days. Then it is 32 days from January 1st to February 2nd. The expected result must be 21 years and 32 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this out

```
$date1 = Carbon::parse("02.02.2021");
$date2 = Carbon::parse("01.01.2000");
```

First get difference of years between 2 dates

```
$y = $date2->diff($date1)->y;
```

once you get years add those years so you will have 2 dates of current year,
and when you get difference of days of current year using Carbon, you will get correct days

```
 $date3= $date2->addYears($y);
```

Complete code

```
    $date1 = Carbon::parse("02.02.2021");
    $date2 = Carbon::parse("01.01.2000");
    
    $years_total = $date2->diff($date1)->y;
    $date3= $date2->addYears($years_total); //2021-01-01 using above example
    $days_excluding_years = ($date3->diff($date1)->days);
    echo $years_total ." Years ". $days_excluding_years ." days";
```

Comment: A good answer would include an explanation of how it works and why it solves the issue, so that both the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: I don't want to add years to days. I want to get years and days excluding years.

Comment: What is years and days without years please? Have you tried the code snippet from @Teekay? +1 from me.

Comment: @Davidos you will get years in $y and days excluding years using ($date3->diff($date1)->days)-1 method

Comment: changed variebles names, it might help to understand

Comment: @jspit added some explanations, it might  help you to get the logic

Comment: @Teekay Sorry, yes that's it. And why diff -1 day?

Comment: @Davidos Carbon difference include startday and endday in calculation. suppose you have dates
3 march to 5 march. if you want difference by adding both dates like 3,4,5 then don't use -1. and if you want 5-3 as 2 then use -1.

Comment: you have a typo on this line `$days_excluding_years = $date3->diff($date1)->days)-1;` will be `$days_excluding_years = $date3->diff($date1)->days - 1;`

Comment: @Teekay I'm using Carbon with laravel and with carbon::parse 02.03.2021 and 03.03.2021 the difference is 1 day, instead of your information 2. It looks like It add only first day not end day too, please check if this -1 is needed :)

Comment: @Davidos thanks for correction, no need to add -1

Answer (score 2):

The same solution with DateTime without Carbon.

```
//Diff in Years and Days (not Month)
$date1 = date_create("01.01.2000");
$date2 = date_create("02.02.2021");
$years = $date1->diff($date2)->y;
$days = $date1->modify($years." years")->diff($date2)->days;

echo $years." Years and ".$days." Days"; 
// 21 Years and 32 Days
```

[Try it yourself in the sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39f6667917a12efd70e629008924c90fce5b30c6).